# Unable to show Popup from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3

I have a tableview where on click of a label I want to show a UIViewController from storyboard using popover method. I have following code in the tap recogniser selector

```
func setupItemNameTapRecognizer(_ label:UILabel) {
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapRecog = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.actionItemNameTap(_:)))
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecog)
}
func actionItemNameTap(_ sender:UIView) {
    print("item tap")
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath )
    self.showPopOverBox(cell: cell!)
}
```

and following code in CellForRowAt method

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemContentCell
        setupItemNameTapRecognizer(cell.itemName)
        cell.itemName.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
```

Whenever I click on label I get following error thrown , not getting whats wrong

> [UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc1867ee90
>   2017-05-23 17:36:23.871 InvoiceMaster[71236:14670269] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > jsut change this method like below

```
 func actionItemNameTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  //  let view = sender.view;
   // print("\(view?.tag)")
    print("item tap")
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: (sender.view?.tag)!, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath )
    self.showPopOverBox(cell: cell!)  
 }
```

Comment: why you written the code in both language `UIView *view = sender.view;`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik dont worry we can always improve each others answers

Comment: sorry , i did not notice that , my mistake.